# Special occurrency counting in data table

Tags: r, algorithm, find-occurrences

(preamble)
I don't know if this is the right place for that...I actually have a problem solving/optimization issue for the counting over a table. So if it's not. very sorry and deserve the minusrating.

Here's the data frame

```
dat <- data.frame(id=letters[1:5],matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,  0,1,0,1,1,  0,0,2,1,0, 1,0,2,1,1, 0,0,2,0,0, 0,1,2,1,0),5,6)) 

# 
#    id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 
# 1  a  0  0  0  1  0  0 
# 2  b  0  1  0  0  0  1
# 3  c  1  0  2  2  2  2
# 4  d  0  1  1  1  0  1 
# 5  e  0  1  0  1  0  0
```

I would like to count along every row, how many times we get to 1 and how many times from 1 we go to 0. so the final results should be

```
# id N1 N0 
# a  1  1 
# b  2  1 
# c  1  1 
# d  2  1 
# e  2  2
```

I actually found an algorithm but it's more C/FORTRAN style (here below) and I can't believe there's not an esaier and more elegant way to get this in R. Thanks a lot for any help or hint.

```
nr <- nrow(dat) 
nc <- ncol(dat) 
rownames(dat) <- seq(1,nr,1) 
colnames(dat) <- seq(1,nc,1) 
dat$N1 <- NULL 
dat$N2 <- NULL 
for (i in 1:nr) { 
  n1 <- 0 
  n0 <- 0 
  j <- 2 
  while (!(j>nc)) { 
    k <- j 
    if (dat[i,k] == 1) { 
      n1 <- n1 + 1 
      k <- j + 1 
      while (!(k>nc)) { 
        if (dat[i,k] == 0) { 
          n0 <- n0 + 1 
          break 
        } 
        k <- k + 1 
      } 
    } 
    j <- k 
    j <- j + 1 
  } 
  dat$N1[i] <- n1 
  dat$N0[i] <- n0 
}
```

Comment: In second row you get twice from 1 to zero, no?

Comment: right! I change the example! thanks!

Comment: Also, row 3 doesn't have a single from zero to 1 Also, you always have values of 0:2 or you can have any value?

Comment: no row 3 is right. I get 1 at column 1 and the 0. so N1 goes to 1 and N0 goes to 1 as well, but then I got other values so nothing should change in the counting

Comment: You want to completely ignore 2s? E.g. 0->2,1->2,2->1,2->0 aren't counted?

Comment: I want to count status 1 and 0 as I wrote above. the other status should be ignored. then, if you can get something more general is more than welcome! :)

Comment: nope. just 0,1,2 but 2 (at least so far) are ignored. just jump from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 as I said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I totally got it, but you can try:

```
cbind(dat["id"],N0=rowSums(dat[,3:7]==1 & dat[,2:6]!=1)+(dat[,2]==1),
                N1=rowSums(dat[,3:7]==0 & dat[,2:6]==1))  
#  id N0 N1
#1  a  1  1
#2  b  2  1
#3  c  1  1
#4  d  2  1
#5  e  2  2
```

Comment: only one precision. in N0 should be `dat[,3:7]==1 & dat[,2:6]==0` I guess

Comment: Oh sure, it depends on the logic you want to implement. If you want to count the number of "0 to 1" transitions, sure. In this answer, I count the number of "any to 1" transitions. I guess you got the idea and can change the values to whatever fits you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using `rle` wrapped in data.table syntax:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

melt(dat, id="id")[, with(rle(value), list(
    n1    = sum(values==1), 
    n1to0 = sum("10" == do.call(paste0, shift(values, 1:0, fill=0)))
)), by=id]

#    id n1 n1to0
# 1:  a  1     1
# 2:  b  2     1
# 3:  c  1     1
# 4:  d  2     1
# 5:  e  2     2
```

*Notes.*

- `shift` with `n=1:0` returns the lagged vector (lag of 1) and the vector itself (lag of 0).
- `melt` creates a `value` column; and `rle` contains a `values` vector.